# chat message block with arrow css

Tags: html, css

I need to make this exact div with right arrow. As you can see it's little bit curved

[image]

Here's what I got. I want to make it a little bit longer and curved as in picture above

```css
.speech-bubble {
      display:inline-block;
      padding:5px;
     position: relative;
     background: #dcf8c6;
     border-radius: .4em;
    }
    
    .speech-bubble:after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     top: 50%;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border: 5px solid transparent;
     border-left-color: #dcf8c6;
     border-right: 0;
     margin-top: -5px;
     margin-right: -5px;
    }
```

```html
  
<div class="speech-bubble"> Hello Mike! Could you please call me back </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use this tool?
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.speech-bubble {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.speech-bubble > span {
  background: #dcf8c6;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.speech-bubble::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 0;
  border-right: 0;
  bottom: 14px;
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -21px;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  width: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.speech-bubble::before {
  background-color: #dcf8c6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 0;
  bottom: 7px;
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -11px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  width: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech-bubble">
  <span>Hello Mike! Could you please call me back</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bubble's code

```
.speech-bubble {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5em 2em 2em 2em;
    position: relative;
    background: #dcf8c6;
    border-radius: .4em;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    color: #888;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

About the right arrow, what about using a background-image (png). If you want that shape you need to use border-radius. Using a .png image is way easier.

By the way, I wouldn't use a unique div to be a container and a text-wrapper...